# User form can't pass value to module

Tags: excel, vba

I've inserted a user form into a project that already contains a bunch of modules. By playing around with the code in the user form, I've verified that I can return the value from a combo box.

User form code:

```
Public SelectedPacking As Integer

Private Sub CancelButton_Click()
    UserForm1.Hide        
 End Sub

Private Sub OKButton_Click()
    SelectedPacking = ComboBox1.ListIndex    
    Call DemoDialogOk

    'Return list index value to cell C50
    Worksheets("Inputs & Results").Range("C50") = SelectedPacking    
    Unload UserForm1    
End Sub
```

My problem is that I can't pass this value on to any of the macros written in the modules.

Module code:

```
Public Sub ShowComboBox()
    UserForm1.Show    
End Sub

 Public Sub DemoDialogOk()    
    ival = SelectedPacking

    'Return value of ival (list index value from combo box) to cell C17
     Worksheets("Packed bed (Random)").Range("C17") = ival
End Sub
```

Obviously the module contains more useful code, but I've commented out everything to try and figure out where I'm going wrong. I've been changing some things around, but I still can't get anything to appear in cell C17, so I think I'm missing something fundamental.

Comment: You need to pass `SelectedPacking` as a parameter to `DemoDialogOK`. Once you unload the form, any variables held by it will be wiped out.

Comment: Yep! So simple, but completely right. Thanks!

Comment: Does this mean that if you were to hide the form instead of unload it, you wouldn't have to pass it to DemoDialogOK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think two options: 1) change DemoDialogueOK to accept variables:

```vb
Public Sub DemoDialogOk(SelPack as integer)    
    ' ival = SelectedPacking

    Worksheets("Packed bed (Random)").Range("C17") = SelPack
End Sub

Private Sub OKButton_Click()
    SelectedPacking = ComboBox1.ListIndex
    Call DemoDialogOk(SelectedPacking)

    ...
End Sub
```

Or option two: fully qualify the variable from the useform i.e:

```vb
Public Sub DemoDialogOk()
     ival = ufYourForm.SelectedPacking

    ...
End Sub
```

Public variables in userforms don't appear to be as "public" as module level...

Comment: Good point raised above: unload will completely kill the form so I don't think you could reference variables from it at all, even fully qualified... I just use .hide rather than .unload

Comment: I just passed SelectedPacking to DemoDialogOK (as with the first option you described) and it worked perfectly. I think since it passes it before it unloads, you are able to reference it.

Comment: To pursue this concept further read [Professional Excel Development](http://books.google.com/books?id=VnegO0pMYlIC&pg=PA379&lpg=PA379&dq=professional+excel+development+userform+instance&source=bl&ots=DvFIRlVgPD&sig=__QJWWOpZevmZH13oXAbin8Nmvk&hl=en&sa=X&ei=5v8fUs74O5DhiwLfvoDABA&ved=0CC4Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=professional%20excel%20development%20userform%20instance&f=false). Start half-way down page 379.

Comment: Hurray my first answer tick, thanks Natalie. Good luck with it ;)

Comment: That's interesting Doug! Didn't realise you could use userform as a class. Good to know.

Answer (score 0):

Tipping on top of Simon's answer, you could pass the entire userform if you'd like. This would give you access to all the pieces of it and is especially useful if you need to do some validation on, say, different checkboxes being checked or not.

```
 Sub inOurUserForm()
    Call inADifferentModule(Me) 'Passes this userform
 End Sub

 Sub inADifferentModule(ourForm As UserForm1)
    'Passed the form, and using it like a class (As whatever the form is called)
    If ourForm.chkYes = True Then
        'Do something
    Else
        'Do something else, like
        ourForm.chkYes = False 'Because we are passing the object itself _
                                 rather than a copy, at least in my understanding
    End If

End Sub
```

And you don't necessarily need to pass the userform, as you could just reference it as an object itselft e.g.

```
UserForm1.chkYes
```

Answer (score 0):

A very easy solution to this would be to declare a variable within the Userform (UserForm1 in this example)

```
    Public Pass as string
```

This Pass would contain the string where you store the password. Once you store the password, you can hide the form

```
    Me.Hide
```

Within the module, you can open the Form as modal

```
    UserForm1.Show vbModal
```

Now after all the code inside the userform is run, the password can be retrieved within the module -

```
    UserForm1.Pass
```

You can then unload the hidden form

```
    unload UserForm1
```